# Where are the Zshell colors set?

Tags: terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm getting these funky colors in my project, - and I have now idea where to disable them. They're ugly and distracting, - and I don't know what they mean. I've tried disabling everything, - but they still appear.

I'm using the [Powerlevel9k-theme](https://github.com/bhilburn/powerlevel9k).

[image: zshell wierd colors]

Comment: Check out the manpage of `ls`. Probably one of your startup files sets `LS_COLORS` and aliases `ls` to `ls --colors=auto`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By accident, I found the answer when fiddling with the colors in my iTerm-setup for executable files. The answer is that it's not Zshell that sets those colors. It's the LSCOLOR-variable which can be found in the `.bash_profile`-file or `.zshrc`-file.

See how to change the colors here: [Change colors on executable files in the terminal (or iTerm2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46322955/change-colors-on-executable-files-in-the-terminal-or-iterm2)